# Getting the value of TbSelect2

Tags: yii, yii-booster

how to get the value of bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2
display in array..

heres my code:

```
$employees = Employee::model()->findAll();
$ctr = 0;
$emp = '';
foreach($employees as $emps){
  $emp[$ctr]=$emps['id'].". ".$emps['lastname']." ".$emps['firstname'];
  $ctr++;
}

$this->widget(
                'bootstrap.widgets.TbSelect2',
                array(
                        'asDropDownList' => false,
                        'name' => 'emp_sel',
                        'options' => array(
                                'tags' => $emp,
                                'placeholder' => 'Type the name of employee and press enter to select',
                                'width' => '100%',
                                'tokenSeparators' => array(',', ' ')
                                )
                     )
             );
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: here is my controller                  if(isset($_POST['EmployeeSchedule']))
    {
    echo $employeeselect= $_POST['emp_sel'];
    }

Answer (score 0):

Try this;
$employees = Employee::model()->findAll();
$emp = array();
foreach($employees as $emps){
  array_push($emps, $emps['id'].". ".$emps['lastname']." ".$emps['firstname'];
}

The tags doesn't need to be an indexed array, just a plain array. See here http://yiibooster.clevertech.biz/widgets/forms_inputs/view/select2.html

Comment: yes I already did that, my problem is I want to add the data in the database thats why I want to get the value of the TbSelect2